# vim winminwidth "E36 Not enough room" error

Tags: vim

I'm having problems setting a 'dynamic' window width in my .vimrc. Doing this for winheight works just fine. Here's the code:

```
" dynamic current window sizing from TBot Art of Vim
set winheight=9
set winminheight=9
let &winheight = &lines - 9
set winwidth=40
set winminwidth=40       " E36 Not enough room here
let &winwidth = &columns - 40
```

The winheight settings work just great; but the winwidth settings get the error.

However, it all works once I'm in vim; I usually have 3-7 related windows open in a single tab and the dynamic resizing means I always have lots of space horizontally and vertically to work in.

Comment: If it all works out in the end, you can suppress the error by prepending `:silent!` to the command.

Comment: Cool! Thanks so much, Ingo Karkat

Comment: If that's fine for you (I couldn't do any better), I've added an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this, and tried to work around it via `:autocmd VimEnter` and other such tricks, but failed.

If it all works out in the end, you can simply suppress the error by prepending `:silent!` to the command.